# How to rearrange groups span through multiple lines?

Tags: regex, notepad++, grouping

## Input

```
14. SEPARATION ANXIETY/265
The Continuing Saga of Zero-Gravity Elimination
```

## Desired output

```
14. SEPARATION ANXIETY – The Continuing Saga of Zero-Gravity Elimination/265
```

## My try

**Find**: `(\d+. (.*))(/\d+\r\n)((.*))`
**Replace**: `\1–\3\2`

```
14. SEPARATION ANXIETY–/265
SEPARATION ANXIETY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not referencing the right groups in the replacement pattern. Your `(\d+. (.*))(/\d+\r\n)((.*))` pattern contains 5 capturing groups and `\1` refers to the text captured with `(\d+. (.*))`, `\3` refers to `(/\d+\r\n)` and `\2` refers to `(.*)` (part of the first capturing group).

Here is a version that will do the job:

```
Find: ^(\d+\.\h.*)(/\d+)\R(.*)
Replace: \1 – \3\2
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `(\d+\.\h.*)` - Group 1: 1 or more digits, a dot, a horizontal whitespace and then any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible up to the last...
- `(/\d+)` - Group 2: `/` and then 1+ digits
- `\R` - a line break
- `(.*)` - Group 3: the whole line.

[image]